# What objects can belong in a group?

Tags: group-theory

> What type of object can belong in a group?

So far I've only seen integers and matrices. Can vectors be in a group? Can operators be in a group?

Someone please help stretch my mind a bit as online notes does not help in this respect. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely anything. Groups are just sets paired with a function that satisfies certain conditions, and sets can contain anything.

Comment: So many good answers in such short amount of time!

Comment: That reminds me of a billboard advertisement for a plumber service I saw which read (with symbols) that frownie face + plunger = smiley face, which got me wondering what more you could derive from that information.  If it was isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$ then it turns out plunger + plunger = frownie face

Comment: @EdwardJiang well, not literally anything. Proper classes can't be elements, for example. At least not in ZF.

Comment: [Ways to flip a mattress can be in a group.](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/05/02/group-think/)

Comment: For concreteness, here are some other simple examples: polynomials (say real, 1-variable) or continuous functions (say from the reals to the reals) form a group under addition.

Comment: @rschwieb I thought proper classes were not an object of ZF.  MathNewb, to complement those good answers, let me also remark that assuming the axiom of choice, any non-empty set whatsoever can be given the structure of a group for some binary operation; in fact the two statements are equivalent.  See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12973/does-every-non-empty-set-admit-a-group-structure-in-zf

Comment: @guest I don't want to hash out details here. I just wanted to say that "absolutely anything" was overstepping. In any of the standard set theories, there are going to be things that can't be allowed to be elements of sets.

Comment: @rschwieb But this is what confuses me.  In ZF all objects of the theory are sets, and all sets are elements of other sets.  The only set that does not admit a group structure, under ZFC, is the empty set.

Comment: @guest that is all true, but I don't see how it is related to the question. Of course, given a set, its elements are sets. Thus things that aren't sets can't be elements (in ordinary set theory).

Comment: @rscwieb, "In any of the standard set theories,  there are going to be things that can't be allowed to be elements of sets."  Exhibit some object in ZF that is not an element of a set.  I don't understand what 'things' are in ZF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any object at all can be in a group. What makes a set a group is the operations with which one endows it, namely, the multiplication map $$G \times G \to G$$
and inverse map $$G \to G$$
satisfying the usual group axioms.

For example, the vector space axioms imply that for any vector space $(\mathbb{V}, +, \cdot)$, the underlying set $\mathbb{V}$ is an (abelian) group under the given addition operation $+$.

And of course, we can think of elements of a matrix group (for example) $G \subseteq GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ as unary operators that act on $\mathbb{R}^n$, e.g., by left multiplication.

Comment: I am somewhat puzzle by the downvote, I'd be keen to know what could be improved by what seems to me to be a wholly straightforward answer.

Comment: I assume whoever downvoted your answer also downvoted mine as well.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you have a nonempty set of stuff, which we call $G$, and some operator $*$ on the set such that for all $a, b, c \in G$,

1. $a * b \in G$;
2. $a * (b * c) = (a* b) * c$;
3. There is an element $e \in G$ such that $e * a = a * e$;
4. For all $d \in G$, there is an element $d^{-1} \in G$ such that $d*d^{-1} = d^{-1}*d = e$;

then you have a *group*.

One of my favorite topics of research is the application of musical set theory (very different from mathematical set theory, by the way), which involves the group structure of the set of twelve musical notes $S$. One would think that musical notes are far removed from math, but for a very long time, 20th-century music theorists have treated $S$ as "essentially being the same" as the integers mod 12, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, creating an *isomorphism* - and then we write $S \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Comment: So e.g. $c*c=a^\flat$ (since $e$ has to be the identity)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm - $(S, *)$ works as in $(\mathbb{Z}_{12}, +)$, with $C = 0$, $C\# = 1$, $D = 2$, etc. So for example, $C * C\# = 1$. This has applications in generating tonal matrices.

Answer (score 6):

Any collection of objects can be made into a group. For example, the set consisting of a Teddy bear and an apple can be made into a group as follows:

Let $G$ be the set $\{$ ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ,  $\}$. Define a binary operation $+: G \times G \to G$ as follows:

ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ $+$  $=$  $+$ ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ $=$ ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ

and

ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ $+$ ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ $=$ 

and

 $+$  $=$ 

The definition of a group is merely a blue print that you can use to spot objects that are groups. That elements of groups are denoted by integers and other collections of numbers is just for convenience:

One reason is that it is easier to write $1$ than it is to write ʕ•͡ᴥ•ʔ.

Another reason is that we expect $1$ and $-1$ etc. to behave in certain familiar ways and the notation delivers this intuition to us at no additional cost.

But these two reasons don't mean that we couldn't write $\mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$ entirely using funny symbols of our own choice.

Comment: All characters appearing in this work are fictitious. Any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.

Comment: A long as real persons have entered the picture, let me add my favorite example of a group: It has exactly one element, namely me. The operation is then uniquely determined.

Comment: @Andreas: Evidently you have a strong sense of identity. I'd encourage you to sing "[I'm My Own Inverse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0s5Kn9QXtU)" but it wouldn't scan.

Answer (score 3):

Anything can be in a group, so long as an associative binary operation with identity (and inverses for each element) is defined. If $V$ is a vector space, then the set of vectors in $V$ is a group under addition. Nonzero rationals, reals, and complexes form a group under multiplication. Invertible linear operators on a vector space form a group under composition. Bijective functions from a set to itself also form a group under composition. Given an alphabet of symbols $a$, $b$, $c$, ..., the collection of all "words" using these letters and these letters with superscript "$-1$"s forms a group under concatenation.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the last example, we need cancellation - i.e. if we concatenate $ba$ and $a^{-1}c$, we get $baa^{-1}c$ and then we need to be able to cancel $aa^{-1}$ to get $bc$. Otherwise we just have a semigroup

Comment: Yes, that's right, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Groups are phrased in terms of set theory, and in ZF set theory "being in" is a relation that holds between two sets.

So, the elements of any set (being a group has nothing to do with it) can potentially be any sets whatsoever.

This matters little in everyday mathematics, though. It is usually safe to think of elements like "points" in geometry.